# Check if object already exist by a variable

Tags: c#, linq, casting, where-clause

I have a var varaible assigned as follows where `x.Item` is of type 'Object'

```
var items = paymentList.Select(x => x.Item).Distinct();
```

say items contain, two values AUTO and ADVANCE.

I have an Object of type `CreditCard`

```
public class CreditCard
{
   public string uniqueId {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list `itemsList` having CreditCard. I want to remove those whose uniqueId "not in" `items` collection.

```
 itemsList.RemoveAll(x => x as ct_CreditCard.uniqueId not in items)
```

say I have two CreditCard object in `itemsList` having uniqueId value as AUTO and BILL.

It should remove CreditCard having uniqueId = BILL since `items` only contain AUTO and ADVANCE

How can I achieve it?

Comment: What you need is casting.

Comment: try this: `itemsList.RemoveAll(x => !items.Contains(((ct_CreditCard)x).uniqueId))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can work

```cs
   itemList.RemoveAll(x => !items.Contains(((ct_CreditCard)x).uniqueId)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works with any enumerable sequence of CreditCards, not only with `List<CreditCard>`

```
var listWithoutItems = originalList
   .Where(creditCard => !items.Contains(creditCard.UniqueId));
```

And if you want to replace your original list with this new list:

```
originalList = originalList
               .Where(creditCard => !items.Contains(creditCard.UniqueId))
               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
itemsList.RemoveAll(crItem => !items.Any(y => y == crItem.uniqueId));
```